# RoleBased Authontication in windows form Application using Custom Attributes?

Tags: c#

I need User Role Based Authentication using Custom Attributes in Windows Forms Application. 
Custom Attributes (Validation Attribute) in MVC is working, But in Windows form, we cannot able to achieve it.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can use `ClaimsPrincipal` for verifying that current user has claims to actions. Microsoft has entire framework dedicated to it

Comment: I have tried ClaimPrincipal and is looks like what I am expecting. However, when the validation fails in the CheckAccess function we are getting System.Security exception and we are unable to capture it.Can you please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Do we have alternate for ClaimPrincipal to achieve Role-based Authentication.

Comment: If your question was answerable, someone already would answer it. I think, you should familiarize yourself thoroughly with MIF, first. Second, research. There are websites dedicated to role-based auth.